# CSS - prevent absolute positioned element from overflowing body

Tags: css, overflow, positioning, css-position

I have an element in a page which is absolute positioned using TOP and LEFT css styles.
When it's positioned at a negative position in the left or top area, it's no problem.
However, when the element is placed at a left position greater than the window innerwidth, scrollbars will appear.

Is there a way to somehow prevent this element from doing that?
I can not set overflow:hidden; to my body element as that will destroy my layout.
For example, a property like `overflow-parent:none;` would be great (but unfortunatly does not exist)

Comment: You mention you can't set `overflow: hidden;` on the body. I'm assuming the reason is that it will break vertical scrolling? That said, have you tried `overflow-x: hidden;` on the body?

Comment: With some example code where we could see it actiually happen we could help you even more.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to work with nested divs which have all some different responsibility:
The outermost sets the position  with left and right simultaniously. The `right:0` sets it to  the right.

The inner div is the real content div, which sets the width.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/atnc3/44/

```
<div class="abs-position">
    <div class="abs-content">
         Absolut Vodka       
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.abs-position {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    left: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.abs-content {
    width: 400px;
}
```

```css
.abs-position {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    left: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* following: just for demonstration purposes */
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid gold;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.abs-content {
    width: 400px;
    /* following: just for demonstration purposes */
    padding: 5px;
    background: lightgray;
}
.container {
    width: 600px;
    background: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="abs-position">
    <div class="abs-content">
         Absolut Vodka       
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
Other content<br>
Other content<br>
Other content<br>
Other content<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Setting the right:0; and bottom:0; and placing the content in a no-width no-height container fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I thought absolutely positioned element did not take up space.  Do you have a 'clear' in your element?

Try floating the element as a quick check?  (float:left);

Comment: What effect would floating have on an absolute positioned element? Does it actually make sense floating an absolute positioned element?

Comment: @laarsk It does not make sense at all. float is ignored for an absolute positioned element.